# Accessing index using list comprehesion in Python

Tags: python, list-comprehension

Hello recently I am trying to figure out list comprehension. And it looks like I suck at this :/

Here is my code I am trying to remake using list comprehension

```
base = datetime.datetime.today()
date_list = [base - datetime.timedelta(days=x) for x in range(61)]
del date_list[0]
date_list.reverse()

weekend = []
dates = []
for idx, val in enumerate(date_list):
    dates.append(str(val)[0:10])
    dates.append(str(val)[0:10])
    case = val.isoweekday()
    if case == 6 or case == 7:
        weekend.append(str(val)[0:10])
```

I looked it out how to use enumerate using this method and i found this:

`[val for idx, val in enumerate(date_list)]`

But i don't know how to continue this idea.

I would really appreciate some help :)

Comment: Is doing `dates.append(str(val)[0:10])` twice intentional?

Comment: Yes, I need it to be this way

Comment: Why the use of `enumerate`? doesn't look like you need the index `idx`.

Comment: Well.. you are right. This is a leftover from previous version. I didn't really think about this. Thanks

Comment: Notwithstanding the fact that you don't need to use enumerate, why use a list comprehension when your loop does what you need? Sure, it can be done using list comprehension but it'll end up being unreadable/unmaintainable

Comment: I heard that list comprehension is faster. So i am trying to speed up my loops

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For list comprehension with if condition it should look like this [function(x) if condition(x) else other_function(x) for x in list]
So for your case, I would say:

```
base = datetime.datetime.today()
date_list = [base - datetime.timedelta(days=x) for x in range(1,61)]
date_list.reverse()

weekend = [date.strftime("%m/%d/%Y, %H:%M:%S")  for date in date_list if (date.weekday()==5 or date.weekday()==6)]
dates=[]
for date in date_list:
    dates.extend([date.strftime("%m/%d/%Y, %H:%M:%S"),date.strftime("%m/%d/%Y, %H:%M:%S")])
```

It's better to use strftime to transform datetime in the format you want: https://docs.python.org/fr/3.6/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior

Comment: I copied ur code but it says there is a syntax error somwhere near `for` in `date.weekday()==7) for date in date_list`

Comment: The list comprehension is incorrect. This should be the right one:
`weekend = [date.strftime("%m/%d/%Y, %H:%M:%S") for date in date_list if (date.weekday()==6 or date.weekday()==7) ]`
The order of the `for` and `if` statement matters.

Comment: Indeed, my bad, to use this you absolutly need a else statement which is not really suitable in your case

Comment: I also belive that `.weekday()` returns different values than `.isoweekday()`. Instead of  `(date.weekday()==6 or date.weekday()==7)` 6 and 7 should be changed like so `(date.weekday()==5 or date.weekday()==6)`

Answer (score 2):

This

```
dates = []
for idx, val in enumerate(date_list):
    dates.append(str(val)[0:10])
    dates.append(str(val)[0:10])
```

can be reworked into list comprehension but beware that you might end with low readibility.
Consider similar but simpler case:

```
digits = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
numbers = []
for val in digits:
    numbers.append(val)
    numbers.append(val)
print(numbers)
```

output

```
[1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7, 8, 8, 9, 9]
```

First step is to rework code such that is there is exactly one `.append`, in this case replace `for` loop with

```
for val in digits:
    for _ in range(2):
        numbers.append(val)
```

As you might check output is same, final step is to rewrite that into list comprehension which in case of nested `for` is shallow-deep to left-right thus outcome is

```
digits = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
numbers = [val for val in digits for _ in range(2)]
print(numbers)
```

This approach might be also used if you have more levels of nesting.